# How to make inner join dynamically based on the number of times a table appears in a column?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic

So basically I want to populate the column named **Mjolnir_Source_ID** of the Tables mentioned in table **Table1**

**TABLE1 = #VerticalTableList**

```
VerticalTableName           VerticalColumnName
Enrollment                     NULL
GradeMaster                    NULL
```

**TABLE2 = Reference.dbo.PrepopulateExceptions**

```
TableName         ColumnName         ReferenceTableName      ReferenceColumnName
GradeMaster        Grade               NULL                       NULL
GradeMaster        CatalogID           ACGradeCatalog             ID
Enrollment         Name                NULL                       NULL
Enrollment         EnrollmentID        ACEnrollmentMode           ID
Enrollment         AcademicLevelID     AcademicLevel              ID
Enrollment         CatalogID           ACGradeCatalog             ID
```

All ReferenceTables mentioned in ReferenceTableName column of Table2 have the Mjolnir_SourceID  columns and i want to concat Mjolnir column of all Reference Tables for each VerticalTableName Table.

We can get Mjolnir_SourceID of each reference Table by making inner join of each VerticalTable with its ReferenceTable based on the columns ColumnName & ReferenceColumnName.

Now Now if the ReferenceTableName and ReferenceColumnName columns are empty for any VerticalTable then we are going to give ColumnName as an input for the concat.

```
SELECT @sqlStr = 'UPDATE a' + char(13) + char(10) + ' SET a.Mjolnir_Source_ID = CASE WHEN ' +
          ' b.ReferenceTableName IS NULL AND b.ReferenceColumnName IS NULL THEN CONCAT('+ 
           VerticalTableName +'.' + 'b.ColumnName,c.Mjolnir_Source_ID)
          ELSE CONCAT(b.Mjolnir_Source_ID, c.Mjolnir_Source_ID) '
          + char(13) + char(10) + '  FROM ' + VerticalTableName + ' a' + char(13) + char(10) 
          + ' INNER JOIN ' + 'Reference.dbo.PrepopulateExceptions b'
          + '   ON b.VerticalTable = ' + VerticalTableName +
          + ' INNER JOIN b.ReferenceTableName c ON c.ReferenceColumnName = b.ColumnName '
          FROM #VerticalTableList
```

The resultant queries for table **GradeMaster** from the above query should look like this

```
UPDATE a
SET a.Mjolnir_Source_ID = CONCAT(a.Grade,c.Mjolnir_Source_ID)
FROM GradeMaster a
INNER JOIN Reference.dbo.PrepopulateExceptions b   
ON b.VerticalTable = GradeMaster 
INNER JOIN b.ACGradeCatalog c ON 
c.ID = b.CatalogID
```

For the table **Enrollment**, the resultant query should be this;

```
UPDATE a
SET a.Mjolnir_Source_ID = CONCAT(a.Name,c.Mjolnir_Source_ID,d.Mjolnir_Source_ID,e.Mjolnir_Source_ID)
FROM Enrollment a
INNER JOIN Reference.dbo.PrepopulateExceptions b   
ON b.VerticalTable = Enrollment 

INNER JOIN b.ACEnrollmentMode c ON 
c.ID = b.EnrollmentID

INNER JOIN b.AcademicLevel d ON 
d.ID = b.AcademicLevelID

INNER JOIN b.ACGradeCatalog e ON
e.ID = b.CatalogID
```

Can anyone please help me out here?

Comment: This has the strong smell of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) if I am honest. What are you *really* trying to achieve here?

Comment: @Larnu Yes it might look like it but i'm seriously stucked here. I can't figure out a way how to do it. Like if there are three reference tables for a specific vertical table. Then how to make sure that it makes three joins for that table?

Comment: That doesn't tell me what your real goal is here. There are very few times you need dynamic SQL, for example. The most common being a dynamic Pivot, or when building scripts to perform operations against every table/database. This isn't one of those times, so what problem are you trying to solve initially here?

Comment: I have just updated the question. Let me know if you need more details??  @Larnu

Comment: Again, that just tells me more about what you are doing here. I'm not asking about your what the above is trying to acheive, I'm asking you what the *real* problem your trying to solve it, as this very much looks like an XY Problem. If you don't understand what that is, have a look at the link in my first comment.

Comment: I don't know where i'm making mistakes in explaining the problem. I want to make sure that it makes Join automatically based on the ReferenceTable and ReferenceColumn?

Comment: OK, let's start the beginning... *Why* do you "need" to use Dynamic SQL here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222005/discussion-between-astroluv-and-larnu).